# Create a single schema dataframe when reading multiple csv files under a directory

Tags: scala, csv, io, apache-spark-sql

I have thousands of CSV files that have similar but non-identical headers under a single directory. The structure is as follow:

path/to/files/unique_parent_directory/*.csv

One csv file can be:

|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|Column_D|
|V1      |V2      |V3      |V4      |

The second CSV file can be:

|Coulmn_A|Coulmn_B|Coulmn_E|Coulmn_F|
|V5      |V6      |V7      |V8      |

The result I want to create is a single Spark Dataframe that merges the files correctly without overlapping columns, the output for the previous example should be like this:

|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|Column_D|Coulmn_E|Coulmn_F|
|V1      |V2      |V3      |V4      |Null    |Null    |
|V5      |V6      |Null    |Null    |V7      |V8      |

The code I am using to create the dataframes is:

```
val df = sparkSession.read
          .format("csv")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("mergeSchema", "true")
          .load(path/to/files/unique_parent_directory/*.csv)
          .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

But I get the following result:

|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|Column_D|
|V1      |V2      |V3      |V4      |
|V5      |V6      |V7      |V8      |

Is there a way to obtain the desired dataframe without running a header unification process?

Comment: you have to create a super schema of all of your files with headers.  once you read your files do union to everything into  one DF. there isnt any other way that i know of.

Comment: @Aaron seems to be on track here. Can you differentiate the file types before you read/load them?

Comment: @Aaron Reading the files one by one and extracting the headers every time I run the process punishes the performance on the cluster.

Comment: @WillD all the files are CSV files.

Comment: @SaadK will the schema of the files be same everytime? if so, create a onetime super schema and read individual files using that schema. then do union as all the DF's will have same column names. it should not be that intensive. if the schema is dynamic for each run i am afraid there isnt any other way

Comment: @SaadK can you try this option and let me know  what happens enforceSchema set to false when you read files.

Comment: @Aaron The schema is dynamic for each run, I have tried setting enforceSchema to false but I get the following exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CSV header does not conform to the schema.`

Comment: Example diff schema:
https://medium.com/data-arena/merging-different-schemas-in-apache-spark-2a9caca2c5ce